# Group Based Authorization in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, authorization, custom-authentication

I have site roles like Admin, User, and that is fine.

But let's say I have an legal application (or anything similar). I have an entity called `Case`. Now, I can have many cases and not all users should have access to any particular case. Let's say Fred and Tom should have access to Case1 but only Gina and Rebecca should have access to Case2?

Pretty simple, right? We have cases, and users can belong to a case. That's the first part. The second part is how to have "Case Roles" so Fred could be an "admin" of Case1 and be able to make major changes but maybe Tom is just a "user" of Case1 and can only do minor things and have read-only access, etc.

I know I will probably need to implement a custom attribute, etc but I can't find any examples on the Web of this particular kind of thing. But I imagine this must be very common in most business applications. (like Basecamp or Highrise, etc)

*UPDATE* Let me give a different example:

Take a project management software as a service application like Basecamp. A user can create a "project." Then that user can can invite other users to her "project." But, the creating user can assign different rights for each user to her project. The basic question is how to do this kind of thing in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I would just crate roles for each of these abilities.  Create a method which can update Case 1 and only admins can access that method.  Create a method to read Case 1 and only users/admins can access that method.  As for the UI, you just going to have to create multiple UI elements and show and hide based upon their roles.

Comment: @Evan-Larsen, how does that solve the basic problem though? The issue is that users can create Cases. I can't hard-code for "Case1" or "Case2." A user might create "Case49" and then want to associate users with it. Also, I don't want to only show/hide links to cases because if a user tries to go to /Case/1/Edit and or whatever and is not the right level of user for that case, I don't want to allow it.

Comment: By the way, I will accept answers. :) Its just all the questions I've asked so far have not had any submitted answers! Is this not a really basic thing though? It seems like almost any business app needs to support something like this.

Answer (score 0):

what i understand from your question is that each case is an entity (a row in db) and you want to have different access rights for different cases (entities) be assigned to different roles. in this case you can have a super admin role that assigns access rights of cases to other roles. based on this information you can write custom atuhorize attribute and fetch permissions given by super admin to currently logged in user/role from database and make decisions on this criteria. Moreover, access rights on creating a case are generic because before creation it does not exist so any one who has right to create a case can create any case (be it case1 or case49). once a case is created permissions of this case can also be set by creator of the case.

Comment: I guess this is sort of what I'm talking about. So I guess my question is what does that look like in terms of the custom attribute? It seems straightforward. Take a project management software as a service application like Basecamp. A user can create a "project." Then that user can can invite other users to her "project." But, the creating user can assign different rights for each user to her project. The basic question is how to do this kind of thing in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: you have to create a little module for rights management where you would define different rights on document (create, edit, delete). once you created a case you can ask creator to assign these rights to other roles/users. For that you have to have separate UI listing all the roles in table or grid with "Allow Edit" and "Allow" Delete" buttons in front of them. on pressing this button you can save that information in database table. once that is done you just have to consult corresponding tables in authorize attribute